# Parse REST API - Push Notification with Custom Data (and where query)?

Tags: rest, parse-platform, push-notification

I've been using Parse REST API for push notifications to targeted users (using "where"), it works well .  I am now trying to add a custom data field so the devices can handle a tapped notification (i.e. redirect to specific object id etc).  From what I have read, I should add the custom properties in the data json node, at the same level as alert, like the documented example below.  But every time I make the request I get a 400 Bad Request.  **But**, when I use the Parse.com web console with json: `{ "alert":"Notification Message","CustomObjectId":"12345" }`  ... it works - I see the CustomObjectId in the push notification (on the parse.com push tab).

**Why is my REST API request failing, but the seemingly same request on the Parse.com website console is working? What am I missing?**

My Parse REST Request:

```
{"where":{"UserId":"MyUserId"},"data":{"alert":"Notification Message","CustomObjectId":"12345"}}
```

Example from documentation (note this is using channels, not a where though) https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#push-notifications :

```
{
       "channels": [
         "Indians"
       ],
       "data": {
         "action": "com.example.UPDATE_STATUS",
         "alert": "Ricky Vaughn was injured during the game last night!",
         "name": "Vaughn",
         "newsItem": "Man bites dog"
       }
     }
```

Thank you for the help,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else running into this, make sure you have "REST push enabled?" set to true in your Parse settings on the website.  It's defaulted to false. Parse seems to allow 5 or so requests through per day with "REST push enabled" set to false.  So after you wire this up, you may think you've successfully integrated with Parse, but then you start getting 400 Bad Request errors.  This would lead many to think the issue is with their code possibly malforming requests or missing required parameters, not an authorization level issue like "REST push enabled" is not allowed.